# Ho to write SQL select statement to fetch data based on some columns (for ex, 5 columns) where the values can be blank?

Tags: sql

How to write a select statement to fetch data based on some columns (for ex, 5 columns)? Values of some of the columns can be blank ("") too but they will be in the query and it will fetch the result.

For example, `Customer` table:

[image]

Suppose, inputs are coming like this:

```json
{
    "CustomerName":"",
    "CIN":"",
    "Email":"arnab.exm@gmail.com",
    "CustomerType":"", 
    "BillingFrequency":"Monthly"
}
```

The values of the inputs can change too, like:

```json
{
    "CustomerName":"TestEGSB",
    "CIN":"",
    "Email":"",
    "CustomerType":"",
    "BillingFrequency":"Monthly"
}
```

How to write a query when it's not known which input will come as field value and it can come as blank too??

Comment: Are you creating APIs? Which technology you are using on the backend?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Yeah @kelvin, I am creating API. For DB, I am using Postgres and I'm using Java in Backend.

Comment: Ok. Got it. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: I don't see any db related question here. You should ask yourself how you're going to handle this in the code, not in the database.

Comment: write a query to do what? select? insert?